# CS50 pset4 blur function - trouble figuring out why the tests fails on 3x3 and 4x4 images

Tags: c, cs50

I've been working on the code for CS50 pset4 blur function.
the function is suppose to calculate the average RGB values of all neighboring pixels, and then apply it to the "middle" pixel (as the pixel can be located on the corners, edges, or anywhere in the middle)

I get no errors when compiling or running the code.
the output images all appear blurred, but when i run the code against check50, it fails on two tests:

```
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n80 9..."
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n80 9..."
```

The other tests pass (testing pixel on edge, corner and middle), so i'm having a hard time understanding what i'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // creating a blank copy
    RGBTRIPLE blured[height][width];

    // upper left corner (anchored)
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            float trackerRed = 0, trackerGreen = 0, trackerBlue = 0;
            for (int k = i; k <= i + 1; k++)
            {
                for (int l = j; l <= j + 1; l++)
                {
                    trackerRed += (float)image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                    trackerGreen += (float)image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                    trackerBlue += (float)image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                }
            }
            blured[i][j].rgbtRed = round(trackerRed / 4);
            blured[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(trackerGreen / 4);
            blured[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(trackerBlue / 4);
        }
    }
    // top middle row
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < width - 1; j++)
        {
            float trackerRed = 0, trackerGreen = 0, trackerBlue = 0;
            for (int k = i; k <= i + 1; k++)
            {
                for (int l = j - 1; l <= j + 1; l++)
                {
                    trackerRed += (float)image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                    trackerGreen += (float)image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                    trackerBlue += (float)image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                }
            }
            blured[i][j].rgbtRed = round(trackerRed / 6);
            blured[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(trackerGreen / 6);
            blured[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(trackerBlue / 6);
        }
    }
    // upper right corner (anchored)
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = width - 1; j < width; j++)
        {
            float trackerRed = 0, trackerGreen = 0, trackerBlue = 0;
            for (int k = i; k <= i + 1; k++)
            {
                for (int l = j - 1; l <= j; l++)
                {
                    trackerRed += (float)image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                    trackerGreen += (float)image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                    trackerBlue += (float)image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                }
            }
            blured[i][j].rgbtRed = round(trackerRed / 4);
            blured[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(trackerGreen / 4);
            blured[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(trackerBlue / 4);
        }
    }
    // left middle column
    for (int i = 1; i < height - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            float trackerRed = 0, trackerGreen = 0, trackerBlue = 0;
            for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1; k++)
            {
                for (int l = j; l <= j + 1; l++)
                {
                    trackerRed += (float)image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                    trackerGreen += (float)image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                    trackerBlue += (float)image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                }
            }
            blured[i][j].rgbtRed = round(trackerRed / 6);
            blured[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(trackerGreen / 6);
            blured[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(trackerBlue / 6);
        }
    }
    // center
    for (int i = 1; i < height - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < width - 1; j++)
        {
            float trackerRed = 0, trackerGreen = 0, trackerBlue = 0;
            for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1; k++)
            {
                for (int l = j - 1; l <= j + 1; l++)
                {
                    trackerRed += (float)image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                    trackerGreen += (float)image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                    trackerBlue += (float)image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                }
            }
            blured[i][j].rgbtRed = round(trackerRed / 9);
            blured[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(trackerGreen / 9);
            blured[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(trackerBlue / 9);
        }
    }
    // right middle column
    for (int i = 1; i < height - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = width - 1; j < width; j++)
        {
            float trackerRed = 0, trackerGreen = 0, trackerBlue = 0;
            for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1; k++)
            {
                for (int l = j; l <= j; l++)
                {
                    trackerRed += (float)image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                    trackerGreen += (float)image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                    trackerBlue += (float)image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                }
            }
            blured[i][j].rgbtRed = round(trackerRed / 6);
            blured[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(trackerGreen / 6);
            blured[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(trackerBlue / 6);
        }
    }
    // lower left corner (anchored)
    for (int i = height - 1; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            float trackerRed = 0, trackerGreen = 0, trackerBlue = 0;
            for (int k = i - 1; k <= i; k++)
            {
                for (int l = j; l <= j + 1; l++)
                {
                    trackerRed += (float)image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                    trackerGreen += (float)image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                    trackerBlue += (float)image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                }
            }
            blured[i][j].rgbtRed = round(trackerRed / 4);
            blured[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(trackerGreen / 4);
            blured[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(trackerBlue / 4);
        }
    }
    // bottom middle row
    for (int i = height - 1; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < width - 1; j++)
        {
            float trackerRed = 0, trackerGreen = 0, trackerBlue = 0;
            for (int k = i - 1; k <= i; k++)
            {
                for (int l = j - 1; l <= j + 1; l++)
                {
                    trackerRed += (float)image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                    trackerGreen += (float)image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                    trackerBlue += (float)image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                }
            }
            blured[i][j].rgbtRed = round(trackerRed / 6);
            blured[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(trackerGreen / 6);
            blured[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(trackerBlue / 6);
        }
    }
    // lower right corner (anchored)
    for (int i = height - 1; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = width - 1; j < width; j++)
        {
            float trackerRed = 0, trackerGreen = 0, trackerBlue = 0;
            for (int k = i - 1; k <= i; k++)
            {
                for (int l = j - 1; l <= j; l++)
                {
                    trackerRed += (float)image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                    trackerGreen += (float)image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                    trackerBlue += (float)image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                }
            }
            blured[i][j].rgbtRed = round(trackerRed / 4);
            blured[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(trackerGreen / 4);
            blured[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(trackerBlue / 4);
        }
    }

    // copy blured image data back to the original image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = blured[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = blured[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blured[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` Are you sure about this `1`?

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't look very generic.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, you'r were right, it wasn't. i rewrote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also in the class so this might be completely wrong but this is what I saw:

```
// right middle column
for (int l = j; l <= j; l++)
```

Your for loop for the int l doesn't seem like it's correct. Shouldn't there be 2 columns?

```
// lower left corner (anchored)
for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
```

j should be width but since its a corner based on your previous code I think it should be 1